# Is the series is convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\log{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}-\log{(\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}})}} $$Give me a hint, because my answer is not so good as I think, it is 0.

Comment: $$\log\frac{x}{\sin x}\sim \log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}\right)\sim \frac{x^2}{6}$$ when $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  when $n$ is very big, try to estimate  $${\log{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}-\log{(\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}})}}$$
as a power of $n$. Compare it to the terms of the divergent sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$